# Please pay attention to the FILENAME and how to print out the filename that I choose from my computer?

Tags: java, bluej

it is a simple question, how to  print out the selected file name, thanks.

```
public class CSVMAX {
public CSVRecord hottestInManyDays() {
//select many csv files from my computer
   DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
   CSVRecord largestSoFar = null;
//read every row and implement  the method we just define
   for(File f : dr.selectedFiles()) {
    FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);
    CSVRecord currentRow = hottestHourInFile(fr.getCSVParser());
    if (largestSoFar == null) {
       largestSoFar = currentRow;
    }
    else {
    double currentTemp = Double.parseDouble(currentRow.get("TemperatureF"));
        double largestTemp = Double.parseDouble(largestSoFar.get("TemperatureF"));
        //Check if currentRow’s temperature > largestSoFar’s
    if (currentTemp > largestTemp) {
                //If so update largestSoFar to currentRow
            largestSoFar = currentRow;
    }
   }
}
return largestSoFar;        
}
```

here I want to print out the file name but I dont know how to do that.

```
public void testHottestInManyDay () {
    CSVRecord largest = hottestInManyDays();
    System.out.println("hottest temperature on that day was in file " + ***FILENAME*** + largest.get("TemperatureF") +
               " at " + largest.get("TimeEST"));
}
}
```

Comment: Does `CSVRecord` contain that information?  If not, can that property be added to `CSVRecord`?  If not, can you create a class which itself contains a `CSVRecord` as well as the other information you want and return *that* from `hottestInManyDays()`?

Comment: You can't. Your actual implemantion just return CSVRecord. You have, at least, return the File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, it seems that `hottestInManyDays()` will need to *return* this information.

**Does `CSVRecord` have a property for that?**

Something like this:

```
CSVRecord currentRow = hottestHourInFile(fr.getCSVParser());
currentRow.setFileName(f.getName());
```

**If not, can such a property be added to it?**

Maybe `CSVRecord` doesn't have that property.  But it can be added?:

```
private String _fileName;

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this._fileName = fileName;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return this._fileName;
}
```

**If not, can you create a wrapper class for both pieces of information?**

If you can't modify `CSVRecord` and it doesn't have a place for the information you want, wrap it in a class which does.  Something as simple as this:

```
class CSVWrapper {

    private CSVRecord _csvRecord;
    private String _fileName;

    // getters and setters for the above
    // maybe also a constructor?  make them final?  your call

}
```

Then return *that* from `hottestInManyDays()` instead of a `CSVRecord`.  Something like this:

```
CSVWrapper csvWrapper = new csvWrapper();
csvWrapper.setCSVRecord(currentRow);
csvWrapper.setFileName(f.getName());
```

Changing the method signature and return value as needed, of course.

---

However you do it, once it's on the return value from `hottestInManyDays()` you can use it in the method which consumes that:

```
CSVWrapper largest = hottestInManyDays();
System.out.println("hottest temperature on that day was in file " + largest.getFileName() + largest.getCSVRecord().get("TemperatureF") +
           " at " + largest.getCSVRecord().get("TimeEST"));
```

(Note: If the bits at the very end there don't sit right as a Law Of Demeter violation, then feel free to extend the wrapper to include pass-thru operations as needed.  Maybe even have it share a common interface with `CSVRecord` so it can be used as a drop-in replacement for one as needed elsewhere in the system.)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the line `for(File f : dr.selectedFiles())`

`f` is a [[File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)]. It has a [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toString%28%29) method [from docs],

> Returns the pathname string of this abstract pathname. This is just
>   the string returned by the getPath() method.

So, in the first line inside the loop, you can put `System.out.println(f.toString());` to print out the file path.

Hope this helps clear a part of the story.

Now, to update this string, I see you are using some object that is called `largest` in `testHottestInManyDay()`. You should add a filepath string in this object and set it inside the `else` block.

Answer (score 1):

One has to return both the CSVRecord and the File. Either in a newly made class.
As CSVRecord can be converted to a map, add the file name to the map, using a new column name, here "FILENAME."

```
public Map<String, String> hottestInManyDays() {
    //select many csv files from my computer
    DirectoryResource dr = new DirectoryResource();
    CSVRecord largestSoFar = null;
    File fileOfLargestSoFar = null;
    //read every row and implement  the method we just define
    for (File f : dr.selectedFiles()) {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);
        CSVRecord currentRow = hottestHourInFile(fr.getCSVParser());
        if (largestSoFar == null) {
            largestSoFar = currentRow;
            fileOfLargestSoFar = f;
        }
        else {
            double currentTemp = Double.parseDouble(currentRow.get("TemperatureF"));
            double largestTemp = Double.parseDouble(largestSoFar.get("TemperatureF"));
            //Check if currentRow’s temperature > largestSoFar’s
            if (currentTemp > largestTemp) {
                //If so update largestSoFar to currentRow
                largestSoFar = currentRow;
                fileOfLargestSoFar = f;
            }
        }
    }
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(largestSoFar.toMap());
    map.put("FILENAME", fileOfLargestSoFar.getPath());
    return map;
}

Map<String, String> largest = hottestInManyDays();
System.out.println("hottest temperature on that day was in file " 
        + largest.get("FILENAME") + largest.get("TemperatureF") +
           " at " + largest.get("TimeEST"));
```